# How to format CSV file data fetched to display on view

Tags: angularjs, csv, angularjs-directive

I am fetching the saved values from CSV file using Custom Directive in Angular JS. But the data that is coming up includes header and I just want to display the first column on my UI.

Sample data that being fetched:

```
Name,Gender,Age,Order,Quantity,Sales
Adrian ,M,14,10,47,11093
Adam,M,13,9,33,2954
Adam,M,14,10,34,1597
Aaron,F,10,6,28,1302
Adya ,F,16,12,34,1292
Aaron,M,9,5,30,839
Alan,F,11,7,24,756
Aimee,F,10,6,19,721
```

Here I want to remove the header and just display the Name column on UI.

I tried using split function but then the new line is messing up the data.

Any ideas around how this can be handled?

Answer (score 1):

```
function myCtrl($scope, $http) {
$scope.readCSV = function() {
    // http get request to read CSV file content
    $http.get('/angular/sample.csv').success($scope.processData);
};

$scope.processData = function(allText) {
    // split content based on new line
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
    var lines = [];

    for ( var i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
        // split content based on comma
        var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
        if (data.length == headers.length) {
            var tarr = [];
            for ( var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                tarr.push(data[j]);
            }
            lines.push(tarr);
        }
    }
    $scope.data = lines;
};
```

}

view

```
<button ng-click="readCSV()">
Display CSV as Data Table
</button>
<div id="divID">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
      <td ng-repeat="y in x">{{ y }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
<table>
</table>
</div>
```